# Simple formula for arduino programming needed

Tags: functions

Im trying to convert the value of a joystick to a useable value
A axis of the joystick outputs a value between 0 and 1 so if the joystick is in the middle it outputs 0.5.

Because i want the joystick to controll the speed of the rotation of a 3d model in max msp i need the value to become smaller and smaller if you move the stick further from the center (regardless of direction)

Im a 17 year old kid with no math skills so could someone help me with a formula to make te value useable?

[drawing of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AEsp.png)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what kind of functions can you implement? can you have absolute value function?

Comment: So you want to transform the interval $[0,1]$ using a function $f(x)$ such that $f(0)=f(1)=3$ and $f(0.5)=1000$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the following function:

```
public double transform(double x)
{
    if(x < 0.5) { return 2*x*1000 + (1-2*x)*3; }
    else { return 2*(1-x)*1000 + (1 - 2*(1-x))*3; }
}
```

which combines the graphs shown below:

[image]

of course the expressions can be simplified so we have

```
public double transform(double x)
{
    if(x < 0.5) { return 1994*x + 3; }
    else { return 1997 - 1994*x; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for including a if else ! works great

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your purpose right, the function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [3,1000]$ which works like this: 
$$f(x)=1994\cdot(0.5-|x-0.5|)+3$$
Is fine for a single axis.

I don't know if it could be implemented for both 2 axes as you desire, could it?

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly